# Make sure Facebook user "register" before login

Tags: php, facebook

If I put the Login button on my site, the user will be able to just log in - and actually do not need to register, How do I make sure the "user" actually REGISTER (so I can save the data in my database) before he can actually log in?

my code for index...

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '*id trimmed*',
  'secret' => '*secret trimmed*',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button>Logga in med Facebook</fb:login-button>

    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is OpenID, then the whole point is to save the data when they log in and to not force a registration

Comment: What is the point of having the Registration pluging if the user actually not need it then?

Comment: Either I don't understand what you're trying to do at all, or you don't actually need a registration plugin. If you need to get more data from the user than Facebook provides, just have a dialog that pops up after the first login requesting it.

Comment: I just want to integrate Facebook log in to my current system, I have saved a "column" in my user table called fid, I just want to fill out the table if its the first time he log in to Facebook, and I don't know how..

Comment: Just check if the data is already in the table, and if not then add it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the user id from facebook with your database, if exists -> login, else -> register:

```
// ...
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user)
{
  $id = $user_profile['id']; // facebook user id;
  // now use this $id to compare with your database saved user facebook user id
  // if not exists, then create user, else update login counter or only get profile
}
//...
```